# Passing Command/Parameter to BackCode?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, parameters

Teaching myself and struggling with what is probably a basic concept. So any additional explanation is welcome... I have the following code which works perfectly from a Button_Click Event and Code Behind. I am ok with using a little Code Behind because it is basically just manipulating the View. However, I want to get the data/business logic from the ViewModel. I am able to confirm (with messagebox.show) that my data is getting passed correctly, however the UI does not update using the new data like it does when data comes from the Button_Click Event. I have been having a difficult time with this for a while and keep finding work arounds. For all I know my approach is totally wrong. I would really like to know how to do this.

WPF

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

        <TextBox x:Name="NumberOfDays" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="GreenYellow" Foreground="Black">

        </TextBox>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="change hello row" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="GreenYellow" Foreground="Black">

            </Button>

            <Button  Content="TestCommand5" Margin="0 0 0 0" Padding="5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding objActiveJobClass.JobID}"
                     Command="{Binding TestCommand5}" 
                     IsTabStop = "False" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource MyFocusVisual}"
                     Style="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource NavigationButtonStyle}}">

            </Button>
        </StackPanel>


        <Label Content="Gant Chart Area" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

        <ScrollViewer Width="1200"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid >
                <Canvas x:Name="GantChartCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Yellow" Height="405" />
            </Grid>

        </ScrollViewer>

    </StackPanel>
```

BackCode:

```
public partial class GantChartUserControl : UserControl
{
    public GantChartUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public GantChartUserControl(int Duration)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateTimeLine(Duration);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int variable = 0;
        if (NumberOfDays != null)
        {
            int.TryParse(NumberOfDays.Text, out variable);
            if (variable > 0)
            {
                CreateTimeLine(variable);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"\"{NumberOfDays.Text}\" is not an INTEGER greater than Zero.");
            }
        }
    }

    public void CreateTimeLine(int duration)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"CreateTimeLine duration {duration}");

        GantChartCanvas.Children.Clear();

        double ControlWidth = 100d;
        int Duration = duration;

        for (int i = 0; i < Duration; i++)
        {
            Label u1 = new Label();
            u1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            u1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
            u1.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            u1.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            u1.Background = IsOdd(i) ? Brushes.Gray : Brushes.DarkGray;

            u1.Height = 30;
            u1.Width = ControlWidth;

            u1.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (ControlWidth * i));
            u1.SetValue(Canvas.BottomProperty, 0d);
            u1.Content = string.Concat("LABEL ", i + 1);

            GantChartCanvas.Width = Duration * ControlWidth;
            GantChartCanvas.Children.Add(u1);
        }         
    }

    public static bool IsOdd(int value)
    {
        return value % 2 != 0;
    }       
}
```

ViewModel

```
private ICommand _TestCommand5;
    public ICommand TestCommand5
    {
        get
        {
            if (_TestCommand5 == null)
            {
                _TestCommand5 = new RelayCommand<object>(ExecuteTestCommand5, CanExecuteTestCommand5);
            }

            return _TestCommand5;
        }
    }
    public bool CanExecuteTestCommand5(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public void ExecuteTestCommand5(object parameter)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"\nDataBaseHelperClass: {System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}");

        int testint = 44;
        GantChartUserControl objGantChartUserControl = new GantChartUserControl();
        objGantChartUserControl.CreateTimeLine(testint);
    }
```

Comment: BackCode is that a thing? - Only know of the term "code behind".

Comment: So... after reading your text you are acutally using the term "code behind" any reason why you named it "BackCode" in title of the question? - And... your text contains way to much noise (not relevant text) that after reading over it the first time I thought "what's the problem"? Maybe rephrase your text without your "story" how it came to your problem, and just simply say what your problem is.

Comment: There are two buttons attempting to achieve the same thing. The Button with the "click event" works using code behind, but the Button tied to the ICommand in the ViewModel (calling the same method in the code behind) does not work. The UI does not update when using ICommand/ViewModel. So I believe I am either not calling the method correctly from the ViewModel or there is something special about updating the UI that I don't know about. (INotifyPropertyChanged is not the problem)

Comment: @mjordan “does not work” is meaningless. Does the execute method get called? “INPC is not the problem” — don’t be so confident in your judgement when you’re at such an early stage in learning about something. INPC is most certainly a critical part of the answer.

Comment: Ok. From my original question: "I am able to confirm (with messagebox.show) that my data is getting passed correctly". I use INPC all the time and I don't believe it is a factor here, but please tell me if I'm wrong. The correct value is being printed in the messagebox so I don't believe INPC is the problem. Overconfidence is not my problem, but I would love to get input that actually addresses my original question ("UI does not update using new data like it does when data comes from the Button_Click Event").  thanks.

Comment: I found a way of Executing the ViewModel method, from Code Behind and getting a static int that is consumed in Code Behind. Code Behind updates the interface the way I expect, (unlike using ICommand to execute the method in the ViewModel).
I (added wpf   x:name = "RefreshGantChart") And added the following to the Button_Click method :
Button RefreshGantChart = sender as Button;
            RefreshGantChart.Command.Execute(RefreshGantChart.CommandParameter);

Duration = ActiveJobViewModel.StaticDuration;
Exactly opposite of what I was trying to do and breaks MVVM, but it works

Comment: @mjordan A static int instead of a return value. I think I understand the underlying problem now. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVVMLight framework, it simplify your binding. 
With this framework you can just create a property `public RelayCommand YourButton{ get; set; }`

And in the constructor of your ViewModel you just have to add this line 
`YourButton = new RelayCommand(Method); // Method is the method to call when you click on the button`

After that, you just need to bind your button on the property.

A little exemple :

ViewModel:

```
    public RelayCommand MyButton { get; set; }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MyButton = new RelayCommand(Action);
    }

    public void Action(){
        Console.Writeline("Button Pressed");
    }
```

WPF

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyButton}" Content="Button"/>
```

When you use binding it's more beautiful to minimize your code behind.

Comment: You need to address OPs confusion about how the usercontrol can reflect the changes in the viewmodel caused by the command. I don’t think his viewmodel has anything in it but the command, which helplessly manipulates a temp instance of the usercontrol.

Comment: I believe you are correct Ed. I can see where I may be creating a temp instance, but I don't know how to manipulate the original usercontrol correctly.

Comment: He can reflect the change in his usercontrol with a mainViewModel. He just need to bind his usercontrol to the mainViewModel and use "RaisePropertyChange" ?
Or maybe i don't understand well the question

Comment: @mjordan This would be a good opportunity for you to learn the basics of data binding with INotifyPropertyChanged. You only need to stay just one step ahead of the student. I learn a lot by researching answers here. (Whoops, you’re OP — same principle applies though).

Answer (score -1):

In your view (xaml), first set the VM as your DataContext. There are ways to do this, but I am going to show you just one:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.GantChartUserControl"
             ...
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"> <!--adjust the location(namespace.folder) of your VM as you like-->
   <UserControl.DataContext>
      <local:GantChartUserControlViewModel/> <!--this sets the GantChartUserControlVM as DataContext-->
   </UserControl.DataContext>
...
```

A View (UserControl) is not supposed to bother to any data manipulation, instead it just shows (binds) to the ViewModel's property that is purposedly to be exposed. I really suggest to put all of those code behind you wrote into the ViewModel. So, what you want to have in the Code Behind (xaml.cs) is:

```
public partial class GantChartUserControl : UserControl
{
    public GantChartUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class GantChartUserControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // boiler-plate
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
       if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   // Property you want to expose:
   public ObservableCollection<int> MyIntegers
   {
       get {return _myIntegers;}
       set { _myIntegers = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyIntegers"); }
   }
   private ObservableCollection<int> _myIntegers;

   // ICommand
   public ICommand TestCommand5 { get; private set;}

   // constructor
   public GantChartUserControlViewModel()
   {
       MyInteger = new ObservableCollection<int>();
       new RelayCommand<object>(ExecuteTestCommand5, CanExecuteTestCommand5);
   }

    public bool CanExecuteTestCommand5(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public void ExecuteTestCommand5(object parameter)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"\nDataBaseHelperClass: {System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}");
        int testint = (int)parameter;
        CreateTimeLine(testint);
    }

    private void CreateTimeLine(int duration)
    {
        MyIntegers.Clear();
        for(int i=0;i<duration;i++)
        {
            MyIntegers.Add(i);
        }
    }      
}
```

Now that you have the VM ready, we need to bind it back to the View. So, back to your xaml, instead of using Canvas, I recommend using ItemsControl (or ListView)

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding MyIntegers, Mode=OneWay}>
        <!--we have the integer collection, but View has the responsibility to set the layout, etc. which I usually call it the datatemplate-->
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalContentAlignment="Center"    
                       Height="30"
                       Width="100">
                     <Label.Background>
                         <Binding>
                             <!--Why empty binding? it just means we are binding to the single int from the ItemsSource-->
                             <Binding.Converter>
                                 <!--What is this converter? We'll get there later-->
                                 <converter: IsOddToColorConverter/>
                             </Binding.Converter>
                         </Binding>
                     </Label.Background>
                 </Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- I see that you wanted to have the labels put in horizontal, so we need to change the itemspanel from the default (vertical)-->
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                <!-- you could use WrapPanel, in case if you want it to wrap, if it does not fit horizontally-->
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

So, the converter above is a tool to convert binded integer into a background color. You would need to create a converter in different class:

```
/// <summary>This convert number to brush</summary>
public class IsOddToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        // value is the integer input, we don't care about parameter or language
        // output should be type of Brush
        if (value is int && targetType == typeof(Brush))
        {
            bool isOdd = ((int)value) % 2 != 0;
            return isOdd ? Brushes.Gray : Brushes.DarkGray;
        }
        // if input (and output) is unknown
        return Brushes.Transparent;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        // We don't care about this
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

So, how do we use this converter? Back to your View (xaml) again. In the UserControl level, please specify the path

```
 xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters" <!--if your converter you defined earlier is inside Converters folder-->
<!--since calling it as converter: IsoddToColorConverter will create a new instance. It might be better to declare this as a static resource, so memory usage won't grow, even if you are using it multiple times. For how to do it, please look in the internet-->
```

Then, voila, this should fulfill the MVVM pattern and your code is much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Note that this is the very basic idea of what you need to do. Eventually you will find some frameworks (`Prism`, `MVVMLight`, etc.) which will help you to cut the number of codes you need to write. And, I really really recommend you to start learning MVVM earlier the better. Coding WPF with old `Forms` style(lots of Code behinds) won't utilize the greatness of WPF.

Comment: At a glance this looks fairly sound, but `Windows.DataContext` and `value as int` won't compile.

Comment: test your code. Test it. Please. int is a value type. Double is a value type.

Comment: If OP is having a problem getting his code to work, how exactly are you helping him by giving him code that won't even compile? Aside from that issue, how is `targetType == typeof(SolidColorBrush)` **ever** going to be true?

Comment: Thanks for your response. It inspired me to rethink my approach.